# What is the way to connect to hive using scala code and execute query into hive?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive

I checked out this link but did not find anything useful :
[HiveClient Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient)

Comment: What do you need to achieve executing those queries from spark (using scala)? Please add more details

Comment: I currently do not want to use spark. I need individual scala code to connect to hive. After connecting want to execute DDL and DML queries.

Comment: I found  code written in java to do this job on this link : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC

Answer (score 0):

From raw Scala you can use Hive JDBC connector: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC. 
One more option is to use Spark Hive context.